# gRPC grpc_completion_queue_next() seems to be unfair when more than one stream is active

Tags: c++, stream, ipc, grpc, rpc

### my use case

I have a server with an async service containing two different bidirectional streaming RPCs (call them stream1 and stream2).
I also have an async bidir streaming client connected to this server.
When the server receives a Read on stream1, it responds with 100000 Writes to the client.
When the client receives a Read on stream1, it saves the response-data into a vector. The client has an alarm triggering a "write_tag" in a loop when the vector of response-data is empty. When it is not empty, it pops first element from the vector (FIFO) and does a Write on stream2.

When the server receives a Read on stream2, it simply responds with a Write.

#### server setup

stream1 and stream2 has their own ServerContexts but share completion queue. I have only one thread which polls the CQ and processes the tag before polling the CQ again... (except for in my second solution to the problem). Each stream instance lives in its own CallData object. The tags are the address of the CallData object in question.

#### client setup

stream1 and stream2 uses separate ClientContexts but share completion queue. It too has only one thread which polls the CQ and processes the tag. Here the tag is an enum which contains all possible operations for both streams, the tags are separated between the streams with READ_STREAM1 and READ_STREAM2 etc..

### my problem

My problem is that the server isnt responding the client on stream2 until it is done Writing on stream1.

[Image explaining my issue (not allowed to post images due to <10 rep)](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8549749/76512092-6c95ab80-6454-11ea-86f7-869dfb94bd6e.png)

### solution 1

If I introduce an Alarm between each write-invocation, it works as it's meant to, but at terrible performance. Same appoach as the GResearch team has in their [article](https://www.gresearch.co.uk/article/lessons-learnt-from-writing-asynchronous-streaming-grpc-services-in-c/). Their code example is [here](https://github.com/G-Research/grpc_async_examples/blob/master/async_streaming_server_queue_to_back.cc#L98).

### solution 2

Another way of solving this, is to have a dedicated thread to get tags from the CQ with CQ->next(), and then store the tags in a queue, from which another thread reads the tags and does the corresponding processing. This too, (due to bad implmementation of busy-waiting) performed really bad.

---

Is there any ideas as to why the Writes in stream1 is prioritized over the Writes or Reads of stream2? My current solution arent good, so would like to get to the bottom with this.

Hope I have made myself clear.